# Use Navigator.getUserMedia() as promise.?

Tags: promise

I want to implement navigator.getUserMedia() as promise.

Then when the promise is resolved I will perform some success callback and at rejection I will perform failure callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
function getUserMedia() {
  var constraints = {
    video: true, 
    audio: true
  };
  var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
  if (location.protocol !== "https:") {
      alert('WARNING: Add https:// before the current url to capture video through WebCam');
      deferred.reject(false);
      return deferred.promise();
  } else {
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
      navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, function(stream) {
        stream.stop = function() {
          this.getVideoTracks().forEach(function (track) {
            track.stop();
            track.enabled = !track.enabled;
          });
          this.getAudioTracks().forEach(function (track) {
            track.stop();
            track.enabled = !track.enabled;
          });
        };
        deferred.resolve(stream);
      }, function(err) {
        deferred.reject(err);
      });
      return deferred.promise();
    } else {
      console.log("getUserMedia not supported");
    }
  }
```